# Want to know about the processor information

Tags: architecture, operating-system

I have seen my system specifications and I was confused in one thing, for the processor it was written
"**INTEL CPU @3.20 Gigahertz 3.2 Gigahertz**"

I want to know why 3.20 Gigahertz is written twice? does this mean I have two 3.20 Gigahertz processors?

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that this means that you have two 3.2 GHz processors. More likely it is simply that the computer code that generates this "processor" field simply uses something like the processor's "short description" followed by its "speed". Unfortunately, the processor's short description already contains the speed, and thus you get the speed mentioned twice (and in two slightly different forms).

That said without some more information on the specific of where this information is coming form it is impossible to answer your question.